# Remove a single space character from a long string of spaces

Tags: java

I am trying to remove a single space character from a long string of let's say 10 spaces. Example (first row is before, second row is after, dots used instead of single spaces for better understanding):

```
".........."
"........."
```

Just one space removal at a time.

Comment: Give is an example input string and expected output string, as well as a code example of what you've tried.

Comment: @Dodd10x it wasn't easy to edit the question and show the proper example.

Comment: Hmmmm you could do this using substring with indexes, easier to do in python with a splice

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza - I'm glad you can read minds.  As evident from the answers below I'm not the only one who thought he might have been asking for something more complex than the extremely simple question it appeared to be.

Comment: @Dodd10x I'm not a mind reader, just read the problem text and rewrite the example, that's all :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really don't are about where the space is removed from (assuming the text is all the same), simply drop the first character, for example...

```
String spaces = "          ";
spaces = spaces.substring(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you  want to remove the fist space of a String you could use this code:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       String a ="123 654 877    98798";
       System.out.println(a);
       System.out.println(a.substring(0,a.indexOf(" "))+a.substring(a.indexOf(" ")+1));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `StringBuilder` for easily removing a character from a string:

```
String input = "123345";
String output = new StringBuilder(input).deleteCharAt(2).toString();
System.out.println(output);
=> "12345"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [String.replaceFirst](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

```
s = s.replaceFirst(" ", "");
```